# How to retrieve the subscriber list from a channel on YouTube?

Tags: java, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to retrieve a subscriber list from a channel that it is not mine. If I go to a channel on YouTube the subscriber list is visible to the public. When I try to use the API to retrieve the list:

```
YouTube.Subscriptions.List list = subscriptions.list("snippet, contentDetails"); 
list.setChannelId(channelID);                                                 
SubscriptionListResponse searchResponse = list.execute();                           
List<Subscription> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();                      
for(Subscription result : searchResultList){
     SubscriptionSnippet snippet = result.getSnippet();
     ResourceId resourceId = snippet.getResourceId();
     String id = resourceId.getChannelId();
    dbConnection.addYouTubeRelationship(channel, id);
}
```

I get the following error:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
> {
> "code" : 403,
> "errors" : [ {
> "domain" : "youtube.subscription",
> "message" : "The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions.",
> "reason" : "subscriptionForbidden"
> } ],
> "message" : "The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions."
> }

I am using an API-key based identification. Please, let me know if and how I can obtain the subscription list from the channels on YouTube.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried authenticating?

Comment: It seems that I did not properly secure my API key.